# ICC/MPI/C++ optimization/fusion of loops not working

Tags: c++, loops, optimization, mpi, icc

I have two simple MPI programs for computing the standard deviation of large arrays of doubles. One is code generated, the other manually implemented. Both perform identically when compiled with GCC, but ICC does some optimizations on the manual version that for some inexplicable reason, it doesn't do on the generated version. I would give a minimal example, but we've found that copying the loop that generates the doubles, and the loop that sums them into a separate function, makes them optimized (fused and vectorized), so I presume it must be something to do with the context. In fact changing the generated code to assign the local sum (v12) to a global (glob) rather than passing it to MPI_Allreduce also makes the loops fuse!

The relevant part of the generated code is:

```
int v4 = v3 / Nproc + (thisRank < (v3%Nproc) ? 1 : 0);
double* v7((double*) malloc(v4 * sizeof(double)));
assert(v7 != NULL);
for (int v5 = 0; v5 < v4; v5++) {
  v7[v5] = v5;
}
int v9 = 0;

double v12 = 0.0;
for (int v8 = 0; v8 < v4; v8++) {
  v12 += v7[v8];
}

double v11 = 0.0;
if (true) {
  MPI_Allreduce(&v12, &v11, sizeof(double), MPI_PACKED, v196, MPI::COMM_WORLD);
}
//glob = v12;
```

The equivalent manual code is:

```
double *create_rand_nums(int num_elements) {
  double *rand_nums = (double *)malloc(sizeof(double) * num_elements);
  assert(rand_nums != NULL);
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < num_elements; i++) {
    rand_nums[i] = i; //2.0; //(rand() / (float)RAND_MAX);
  }
  return rand_nums;
}

int main(...) {
    // ...
  double *rand_nums = NULL;
rand_nums = create_rand_nums(num_elements_per_proc);

// Sum the numbers locally
double local_sum = 0;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < num_elements_per_proc; i++) {
  local_sum += rand_nums[i];
}

double global_sum;
MPI_Allreduce(&local_sum, &global_sum, 1, MPI_DOUBLE, MPI_SUM,
            MPI_COMM_WORLD);
// ...
}
```

Please find the full source code, diss-assemblies, and ICC (HLO) optimizer reports at
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/q6pygs1ag71wugg/SXZvZXTQGH/stddev-mystery

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks :)